# How to integrate SCSS to my code

Tags: php, sass, integrate

I cannot find a way to introduce SCSS on my code. I want to change this:

```
<link href='css.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

to

```
<link href='css.scss' rel='stylesheet' type='text/scss'>
```

But it doesn't work. Even changing the type='text/scss' to type='text/css'.
How to intergrate SCSS to code.

PS: I'm using the latest OSX.

Answer (score 1):

SASS/SCSS is a CSS-preprocessor ([What's a CSS Pre-Processor?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IiujOinbGzw)), not a different version of CSS. This means SASS is not interchangeable with a regular stylesheet, so you cannot just link a SASS file into a web page as you normally would with CSS.

Instead, you create a SASS stylesheet, and then convert that into proper CSS.  You can also use tools that are capable of doing processing/linking SASS automatically, like [Sprockets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets) is Ruby. Also in Ruby, you can use the `sass-convert`command from terminal to convert any SASS/SCSS to CSS, like so:

```
$ sass-convert style.sass > style.css
```

There are also PHP tools like [PHPSass](http://www.phpsass.com/) ([see this discussion for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218712/any-good-sass-parser-for-php)).